# how to change the label text if date displayed in textbox2 is greater than textbox1?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have textbox in my asp.net 3.5 VB.net webform

in my textbox1 the text is : 30-Dec-2010, 06:00:00 PM

i want when the date in textbox is greater than textbox1 then the Label text would be "No REfund ! Sorry"

How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ASP.Net CompareValidator for this purpose. You can check both on client- and serverside. Besides i would recommend not to have Date AND Time in one Textbox. That makes it more difficult to validate and it's not standard, so it might be confusing and error-phrone for users.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBox1" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThan" runat="server" ErrorMessage="No REfund ! Sorry" EnableClientScript="true" ></asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:Button ID="BtnPostback" runat="server" Text="postback" />
```

On the serverside you should also trigger the validation(f.e. if javascript is disabled):

```
Private Sub BtnPostback_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnPostback.Click
     Page.Validate()
     If Me.IsValid Then
         'Do something f.e. save'
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[CompareValidator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you do it using javascript because this functionality does not require postback. A similar question has been posted on stackoverflow which compares two dates using javascript. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript). You just need to extend it to incorporate assigning text to the label.